# std::shared_ptr with aliasing constructor, is it possible the retrieve the initial pointer value?

Tags: c++, c++17, shared-ptr

This c++17 code uses shared_ptr's [(8) aliasing constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  auto shared_1 = std::shared_ptr<int[]>(new int[10], std::default_delete<int[]>());

  int* p_data = shared_1.get(); 

  auto shared_2 = std::shared_ptr<int[]>(shared_1, p_data + 5); // aliasing constructor

  std::cout << std::hex << p_data << "\t" << shared_1.get() << std::endl;

  std::cout << std::hex << p_data + 5 << "\t" << shared_2.get() << std::endl; // Is it possible 
                                                                              // to retrieve the
                                                                              // initial p_data value?
}
```

and prints:

> ```
> 0x556f38865e70    0x556f38865e70
> 0x556f38865e84    0x556f38865e84
> ```

**Question:**
imagine that I only store `shared_2` (and not `shared_1` nor the `+5` offset), does this  `p_data` initial value (stored in `shared_1`) is lost or if is it still possible to retrieve it from `shared_2` only?

Comment: If all you have is `shared_2` then its pointer is all you have. There's no way of knowing how it was constructed or what kind of data it might point to. If you need to get the "original" pointer you need to keep track of it yourself.

Comment: ^^ Yup, the only thing shared between the two shared_pointers is the control block, which is not exposed to the public API.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks, that was my question. I wanted to be sure before introducing an extra storage to store the offset. You can turn your comment into an answer I will be glad to upvote it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The aliasing constructor for shared_ptr has existed since the dawn of time. Another (rvalue) overload was added for it in c++20.
This code uses the earlier constructor. The tag shouldn't change.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - It isn't. It just got an overload for shared_ptr rvalues, which isn't in use here. There was an aliasing c'tor since C++11 that took by const reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot retrieve `p_data` from `shared_2` alone.

The value stored in `shared_2` need bear no relation to the original pointer, and there is no way to retrieve the "original" value used for the initial `shared_ptr` with which the aliasing pointers all share the same management block.

You could use a custom deleter, and store the data in the deleter when you made the `shared_ptr`, and then use `get_deleter` to retrieve the deleter, and thus the data from it.

Comment: Doesn't `shared_ptr` store the "original" pointer in the control block, to be able to destroy the complete "original" object?

Comment: Yes, it does, but you can't get it back via the public API.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin It's probably stored in an opaque form and not accessible by the interface of the control block (interface exposed to `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr`).